# How to add memory profiling options to stack test

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

when running `stack test --profile` it automatically adds the -p rts option.
I am trying to do some memory profiling on my test suite and so would like to add the hc, or hy rts option.

This doesn't seem to work

`stack test --profile --ghc-options="+RTS -hc -RTS"`

it gives the error

`ghc: the flag -hc requires the program to be built with -prof`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have to guess, you intend the +RTS options to be passed to the final  test program, but in your invocation above it might be that those options are being received by the ghc executable itself; like you are telling to ghc "compile this code but please profile your memory while you do that". My suggestion is to build the tests with profiling enabled (for example by running the tests first with `stack test --profile`, although probably you can also use some form of `stack build`) and then run the generated test executable (with profiling) passing the RTS options.

Comment: How can I run the test executable other than via `stack test`?